# How do I use $variable inside single quotes in this case?

Tags: php

Suppose I have the following code which prints out an item price statically as shown below:

```
define ("itemprice1", "20");
```

How do I correctly replace the number *20* with `$price` variable name inside the double quotes?

I tried `define ("itemprice1", ".$price.");` but as you may have already guessed, it just printed out .$price. in plain text ....[laughs]

Comment: use `define ("itemprice1", (string) $price);`

Comment: Worked well! Thanks so much! Maybe edit your comment as an answer so I can upvote you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
define ("itemprice1", (string) $price);
```

**Note:** Define the constant name as UPPERCASE is better for readability. eg `define ("ITEMPRICE1", (string) $price);`

**Edit:**

use

```
define ("ITEMLINK1", "item.php?id=" . $price);
```

Comment: Okay! And hey May I ask you one more question please? What if I wanted to get the price variable of the following page which is `item.php?id=82` as defined here - `define ("ITEMLINK1",    "item.php?id=82");` is it posible to do that?

Comment: output itemlink1 - i think its near impossible to work the way i want anyway. So thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$price = '20';
define ("ITEMPRICE1", $price);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this code it is tested.

```
<?php 
$price = 20;
define('ITEMPRICE1', $price);
print ITEMPRICE1;
?>
```